# Disable user hook in sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm using sails on a project hosted on Heroku. I have a web process running a sails web server and a worker process using the same Models as the ones used by the web server.

In order to make it possible I have different way to start each process with the same code :

1. the app.js standard way
2. a worker.js file that starts the same sails app with only the orm and services hook activated.

However I have added some user hooks in a api/hooks folder that I don't want the worker to start. Is there an easy way to disable those hooks? I tried to lift sails with a { "userhookname" : false } passed in config but it does not seem to work.

Thank you

Comment: You can disable all userhooks via  `sails.lift({ hooks: { userhooks: false } });`. https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2983

Comment: That's a first step but like you I would definitely need to be able to disable a specific userhook and not all of them...

Comment: you can disable custom hooks changing "userhooks" with the hook you want to unload ```sails.lift({ hooks: { custom_hook: false } });```(I know i am a bit late)

Answer (score 3):

Sails.js doesn't currently support disabling individual user hooks in the same way as the core hooks, although it certainly makes sense to implement that feature.  In the meantime, the simplest thing to do is to just implement a toggle within the hook itself.  In the `defaults`, provide an `active` key that defaults to `true`, and then in `initialize`, check that `active` is `true` before continuing.  See [sails-hook-autoreload](https://github.com/sgress454/sails-hook-autoreload/blob/master/index.js#L17) for [an example](https://github.com/sgress454/sails-hook-autoreload/blob/master/index.js#L37).

Comment: Thanks Scott. Could you put this feature on the roadmap?